# Permission cascading/inheritance in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, permissions

I have a system with three layers: A Web client, a Servlet (TOMCAT) and a SQL Server with data and logic.

The client sends request towards the Servlet who forwards it to a single Stored Procedure (let's call it DISPATCHER). The DISPATCHER examines the nature of the request and invokes another stored procedure aimed to handle the specific request received.

The Serlet's connection takes place using a specific set of credentials (let's refer to it as Web_Client) and EXECUTE permission for the DISPATCHER had been granted to it, while no access was defined for any other element (procedure, table, view, etc.).

To my surprise, though the Web_Client is entitled to execute the DISPATCHER, an error message is received when it invokes **SOME** inner procedures (while others do not generate any error).

What could be the reason for this strange behavior?

Comment: So your question is: if I have outer sp and my user has only execute on this sp, is it enough to execute all the inner sp?

Comment: Generally, permissions flow from the SP granted EXECUTE to all other stored procedures and tables used within. The lateral execution will be broken when execution flows to an object created by another schema or owner. I am pretty sure a DENY permission will also break the execution flow, however, you might want to check on that. Is there more information in your error message? Can you post the exception?

Comment: @sepupic, the user will NEVER attempt to execute an inner SP directly. The invocation of the inner SP always takes place from the DISPATCHER.

Comment: @RossBush, right now I cannot send you the message because (in development phase) I simply bypassed the issue by granting to the Web_Client ownership of the DB. Still, the message was crystal clear: **...NO PERMISSION TO EXECUTE...**. By the way, I also shows this message regarding a User-Created Type (EXECUTE!?!?).

Comment: @FDavidov - I would say that is a start. Usually no permission to execute will give you a pointer to where to look. Perhaps the item that your operation was denied on has special permissions or other limitations applied. Is it another SP?

Comment: >>>The user will NEVER attempt to execute an inner SP directly<<< I did understand this. I just wanted to narrow down your question, because it contains too much irrelevant information while it lacks the clear question

Comment: @sepupic, **irrelevant information**. My apologies. I thought the question is short enough while containing all the needed information. Perhaps, I didn't understand your comment to begin with. Care to rephrase?

Comment: @FDavidov I think sepuspic's comment is in response to RossBush's first comment. If you reed the answers you will understand what sepuspic is writing about.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I read it again (twice actually) and, unless my command of the English language is vaporizing, the message remains unchanged.

Comment: Thank you, Zohar Peled. What I really tried was to narrow the question that has nothing to do with TOMCAT, DISPATCHER, etc. I think I could express this question like this: I have outer sp and some inner sp, I granted EXECUTE permission on outer sp only to my user, so how it could be that some inner proc throws an error about missing permissions? And all I want was just the confirmation

Comment: @sepupic Appologies, I've must have misread your comment. Seems like I could use some  coffee :-)

Comment: @sepupic, when I read your alternative phasing it appears clear **BECAUSE** I know the details of the issue. Someone else might ask "why granting permission to one procedure only?". So, I added few lines to describe the scenario and the problem within it. Altogether, not too much to read, only 144 words (I've see questions longer than the Holly Bible).

Comment: Sorry if you thought that I wanted to teach you how to ask the questions. It's NOT what I wanted. I ask you if I understood correctly your problem when described it without irrelevant(as I understood) details

Comment: Did you find the issue? Was it the proc with different owner?

Comment: @sepupic, don't worry my friend. I was not complaining. I simply tried to substantiate and justify my phrasing which, personally, I found it better (but that is just a matter of taste and hence not worth any discussion).

Comment: @sepupic, not yet. Right now I have to solve other issues and return to this in the next few days. It will not be easy because I need to find the "CHAIN" that causes the issue. Anyway, will post here whatever I find. Last, I wish to thank you for your time and dedication. Have a great day!!

Comment: It's not so difficult if you get the whole error message. The object on which the permission is missed is the key. Or this object itself has another owner, or it is used in dynamic code, or the inner procedure calling it has different owner

Comment: @sepupic, yes, I know. My problem is to find which SP is triggering the error.

Comment: You should start from object itself. First control its owner, and only if it's the same use sys.sql_expression_dependencies to find the calling procedure, filter it by the problematic object

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is ownership chaining.

You can read more on it here: [Ownership Chains](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676(v=sql.105).aspx)

In a few words, the permissions are NOT checked if there is unbroken `ownership chain`, i.e. your outer proc and your inner procs have the same `owner` and all the objects within them have the same `owner`.

`Ownership chain` is broken in case of different owners, in case of `dynamic sql` or different databases.

So what you need now is to read the error message with attention and check the owner of the object on which there is no permission, it's there where the chain is broken.

About `DENY`. `Deny` would not provoke this error if the ownership chain is unbroken, it's because the permissions are not checked in this case, so `DENY` is not check either.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Zohar (see above) pointed in the same direction, but 2 minutes after you. So if Ownership Chain is the issue, you will be the one to get my vote :-). Thanks!!!!

Comment: @FDavidov Even if I would have posted first, assuming we are correct, I would have asked you to accept sepupic's answer, since they are basically the same, and sepupic needs that 15 rep points more than me. However, If you find our answers helpful you can always upvote them both :-)

Comment: @ZoharPeled, will do :-).

Comment: Sepupic and @ZoharPeled, the first intuitive check I did was to use the procedure `sp_stored_procedures` to verify who owns he SPs. They are all shown with the same owner. Hence, unless I'm missing something, the **Ownership Chain** would appear it is not the issue. Am I missing something?

Comment: If all the procedures are owned by the same login that ownership chain should work for all procedures, Unless some of these procedures use database objects that are **not** owned by the same owner - and this will break the chain.

Comment: Small correction: procedures cannot be owned by login, only by **user**.

Comment: Small correction N2: he could use dynamic code in one of the inner procedures, so even if they all are owned by the same user, the permissions are still checked

Comment: @sepupic, I did a little investigation by adding/removing ownership to the DB. The strange thing is that, without the ownership, some SP work while others don't. **With** ownership, all works of course. Also, as posted before, all SP belong to the same user (i.e. the one of the `Dispatcher`). So, it would appear that it is not related to the Ownership Chain or, perhaps, I'm missing something...

Comment: What do you mean saying "by adding/removing ownership to the DB?" Do your stored procs go to other databases?

Answer (score 0):

To me, it seems like an [ownership chain](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676(v=sql.105).aspx) problem.

> When multiple database objects access each other sequentially, the sequence is known as a chain. Although such chains do not independently exist, when SQL Server traverses the links in a chain, SQL Server evaluates permissions on the constituent objects differently than it would if it were accessing the objects separately. These differences have important implications for managing security.

The basic concept of ownership chain is that when you are granted access to a database object - a stored procedure in your case - your permissions are not checked for any other database object that the stored procedure uses if it is owned by the same login that owns the original stored procedure.
If the original stored procedure use some database object that is not owned by the owner of the stored procedure, then you will have to have permissions to use this object.

Please note that the user that execute the first object in the chain doesn't need to be that object's owner, just to have execute permissions to it.

So in this case, it seems that the inner procedures that throws the execute permission denied error simply belongs to another login.

Comment: Hello Zohar. This _cound_ be the root of the problem, though I would need to check. The fact is that almost all the procedures within the schema (exceeding 100) I wrote, so it will not be easy to pin-point a test case. Still, will give it a try and let you know. Cheers!!

Comment: If it's always the same inner procedures that raises this error, it's a good sign that we are on the right path. If you know at least one procedure that raises this error, you can simply check if the login that owns your `DISPATCHER` procedure also owns that procedure. If not, we've found the problem.

Comment: Don't know. Need to remove the ownership and re-test. Will let you know (it might take some time though and I hope will remember to put my finding in here).

Comment: Zoar, , I did a little investigation by adding/removing ownership to the DB. The strange thing is that, without the ownership, some SP work while others don't. **With** ownership, all works of course. Also, as posted before, all SP belong to the same user (i.e. the one of the `Dispatcher`). So, it would appear that it is not related to the Ownership Chain or, perhaps, I'm missing something...

Comment: Can you identify the procedures that throw the permission error? from what I understand, it's not enough that the procedure itself has the same owner, everything that the procedure uses must also have the same owner, otherwise the ownership chain is broken.

Comment: Zohar, I use the SP `sp_stored_procedures` and saw that **all the SPs belong to the same user** (me).